# Need help understanding this multivariable calculus problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In my lecture notes the professor introduces quadratic optimization problems by the following cost function.

$$ f(x) = 0.5 \cdot x^T \cdot Ax + b^Tx $$

Matrix A is: \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}

b is: $$(-1,2)^T$$

We should show that the global minimum exist.

The first part of the solution is:

$$ f(x) = 0.5 \cdot x^T \cdot Ax + b^Tx = 0.5 \cdot \sum \limits_{i,j = 1}^n x_i\cdot A_{ij} \cdot x_j + \sum \limits_{i = 1}^n b_ix_i$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 0.5 \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n A_{ij}x_j + 0.5 \cdot \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n x_jA_{ji} + b_i = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n A_{ij}x_j+b_i $$

$$H_{ij}(x) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_ix_j} = A_{ij}$$

I can see how the first part translates into sum notation.

I have no idea how to arrive at the second row. Can somebody help me or give a hint?

Comment: Matrix with entries $H_{ij}$ is in fact $A$ : you have to show that it is positive definite (consider the $n=1$ case: where the expression reduces to $\frac12Ax^2+bx$ which has a minimum if and only its second derivative $A$ is $>0$).

Comment: @JeanMarie Is n the dimension? But when n=1 how do I create Hessian matrix?

Comment: It is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, i.e., a number.

Comment: I still don't understand what this terms with sum notation mean. To show it's positively definite  we find an algebraic expression of quadratic form x^T * A * x and proove algebraically that it is always > 0...(by rearranging terms, quadratic completion)

Answer (score 1):

After taking a break and going over the problem again I finally understood the solution.

This line which gave me headaches describes how the partial derivative is calculated with respect to $x_i$. The partial derivative is needed in order to form the gradient to find the critical points.

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} = 0.5 \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n A_{ij}x_j + 0.5 \cdot \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n x_jA_{ji} + b_i = \sum \limits_{j = 1}^n A_{ij}x_j+b_i$$

The line $$H_{ij}(x) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_ix_j} = A_{ij}$$ basically says that the second derivative of the function

$$f(x) = 0.5 \cdot x^T \cdot Ax + b^Tx$$ yields the matrix A. Derivative with respect to x1x1 yields matrix entry A11, x1x2 yields matrix entry A12 and so forth. So the hessian IS the matrix A. This seems to be a special property of this function, which maybe someone else could illuminate better.